# PostgreSQL + EF6 + .Net 4.0. Не добавляеся поставщик данных

Tags: postgresql, .net-4.0, entity-framework-6, database-first

господа!

Мне нужно написать приложение, которое работало бы с XP с EF6 и брало инфу из PostgreSQL. Что я сделал:

1. Установил EF6 через Nuget
2. Установил EntityFramework6.Npgsql версии 3.1.0 (Вроде бы она последняя, которая поддерживает .Net 4.0)
3. Добавил в App.config строку как тут: [Инструкция по установке Npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/installation.html)

Хотел сделать по методу Database First, т.к. база уже есть, нужно только данные из нее получать.

Дальше мои дйствия:

1. Добавляю папку "Database Models"
2. Жмякаю ПКМ на папку -> Добавить -> Создать элемент...
3. Выбираю "Модель ADO.NET EDM" и ставлю название (Например, User)
4. Выбираю "Конструктор EF из базы данных"
5. Никаких подключений у меня нет, так что жмякаю на "Создать соединение"

Вот тут-то как раз и нет в Источниках данных мною такой желанный PostgreSQL. Никак не могу понять, почему так. Я уже все перепробывал: перезагружал проект, билдил, еще какую-то ересь делал, но все равно ничего непроисходит.

Вот мой packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />    
  <package id="EntityFramework6.Npgsql" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Npgsql" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

А это App.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Не могу понять, как добавить правильно поставщика? Помогите, люди дорогие...

Comment: А расширение VSIX в Студию ставили?

Comment: Нет, я прошу прощения, я нуб, а что это такое?

Comment: И как поставить, если не трудно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из-за своей невнимательности и малой практики не поставил [расширение для VS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration).
Я много ожидал, но не такой абсолютно простой и нубской ошибки.
Спасибо @AlexanderPetrov за его комментарий!